# Alternative online payment gateways

Tags: php, e-commerce, payment-gateway, paypal

I am developing an e-commerce web wite. Now I achieved the step of on-line payment. So I'm looking for best methods to do the job (I already have Paypal, but I am looking at other options to make it easy for the user)

Comment: Not.everyone has a paypal account. It's better to.support Visa / Mastercard billing. I'm sure your local banks have ready to use e-commerce solutions. We cannot do that research for you. But supporting credit cards is definitely the way to go.

Comment: you don't need a paypal account; you can still pay with a cc via payapl

Comment: @dagon oh cool I didn't know that. Then is there any advantage to look for alternatives? Processing fees maybe?

Comment: sure fees, support and features, i only paypal for small clients, bigger clients are usually better off with the bigger processors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One viable alternative to PayPal is Google Checkout. There are some PHP examples for Google Checkout [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_PHP).

I believe that Google Checkout does allow guest purchases, so anyone without a Google Account should still be able to pay with a credit card without creating an account.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with PayPal, I have been using it for multiple eCommerce sites and it has been a breeze.
You can go with PayPal Payments Advanced 
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced

Which keeps them on your site without redirecting (I believe, however the user will still know you are using paypal as the processor since it will have branding.. but not sure on this). This costs $5 a month + processing/transaction fees

If you want a truley seemless(no branding, you can use API calls) you can go with Paypal Payments Pro, however this is $30 a month

Answer (score -1):

I work for Plimus which is an online payment service supplied by a company called bluesnap. You can see an example of a BuyNow page: [*here*](https://sandbox.plimus.com/jsp/buynow.jsp?contractId=2129424). 
As you can see, there are more than quite a few payment-methods/currencies/languages which are supported.

The Buy-page is fully customizable. If you want to play with it, you can open a vendor account on https://sandbox.plimus.com and follow the "start-up guide". The business model is simple: you don't pay for registration or any other monthly/hidden fees. You pay only a certain percentage of every sale you make. The percentage is set according to the transaction amount and varies between 10% (with minimum of 0.75 cent) to 4%.

For more questions feel free to email: [vendors@plimus.com](http://mailto%3avendors@plimus.com)

Comment: i'm sure you are well meaning, but it does read like an advert.

Comment: @Dagon I am not the owner nor a share holder (I'm just an engineer). when you downvote you say that my answer is not useful. do you really think that ?

Comment: i think the idea was for u to see the different payment methods you can choose from. there are many processing engines out there that give better or worse results per card type and currency, and even country. and they give different rates. paypal are not that great but that also depends on the amount of traffic you have. but you can also see payment methods that are not credit card. some are very interesting for clients that are companies or for payments for big amount. it may read like an advert but since he is writing something that technically might compete with his company...

Comment: Thanks Yael. Indeed, one of the main points was to display different payment options. Further, if you choose currency as Euro and Country as Netherlands (for example) - you'll be able to see iDeal which is a local payment method, etc.